# How to use variable shadowed by column in dplyr mutate

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse

Given a data frame `df` and a local variable `z`, I'd like to set the column `y` of `df` to be equal to `z`:

```
df <- data.frame(x=1:5)
z <- 5
df %>%
  mutate(y = z)
```

However, if a column named `z` already exists in `df`, this sets `y` equal to that column instead of equal to the value of the local variable:

```
df <- data.frame(x=1:5, z=4)
z <- 5
df %>%
  mutate(y = z)
```

How do I ensure that I'm setting it to the local variable instead, regardless of the columns present in `df`?

(I understand that I could rename/drop the offending columns, but I'm dealing with data whose columns are not known ahead of runtime.)

Comment: `df %>%
  mutate(y = !!z)` ?

Comment: `df$z <- NULL` after `z<-5` before you call `mutate`

Comment: Or `df %>% mutate(y = {{z}})`.

Comment: Axeman, your `!!z` solution is the only one recommended so far that works inside of a function where `z` is an argument (instead of only working for global variables), so if you post that as an answer I'll accept it.  Thank you!

Comment: No need (and I can't), since there is a duplicate question with the same answer. It is preferable to just link this question to that one, and you can upvote there.

Comment: Ah I see, works for me; thanks!  Meta: how did you locate the duplicate?  I spent about 20 minutes searching before posting, but mostly found questions about using variables for column names.

Comment: Searched `"dplyr refer to external variables"` in duckduckgo, second hit. (Note that we can often find good duplicates quickly because we search for specific code in the answers instead, but I didn't do that here. In many cases, you should not see a duplicate closing as a negative comment on your effort, prolific users here are just more likely to find these things. Although some never bother to look.)

Comment: Awesome, and yep, no negativity assumed -- was looking to post-mortem improve my Google-fu.  Appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

An option is to check for the object in the global environment instead of the local environment

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
   mutate(z = .GlobalEnv$z)
```

Comment: another would be `df %>%  mutate(new_col = get('z', envir =.GlobalEnv))`

Comment: This does answer the question as stated, but doesn't work if z is a local variable inside of a function (which turns out to be my actual use case).  I'm guessing I can instead get the environment for that function, but the `!!z` solution in a comment above seems simpler.  Marking this as answer for now, will probably switch to the other if it's posted as an answer.

Comment: @CoreyStaten  If that is the case, you can use the `!!`

Comment: As far as I know, this is not the recommended method.